# Macbook retina 2012: CPU temperature too high

Tags: macbook-pro, temperature

I'm using Macbook Pro Retina Mid 2012 with CPU core i7 2.7 Ghz. I see that my computer is too hot as I think for a mac. The keyboard is hot,too.

I'm using `iStat` software to get detail of my mac. Here is my detail:

[image]

As you see, four cores are in high temperature. But as I see in `Activity Monitor`, they're just work at about 5% and 95% is idle. I don't know why the heating is too high. are there any problems with my mac. If not, does this problem from software ? How can I fix this. I think 2000-2200rpm is slow for this temperature. Should I increase fan's speed. Thanks :)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two likely issues afoot here:

1. Your System Management Controller has gotten some corruption.
2. You're seeing potential hardware-/sensor failures.

To reset your SMC, follow these instructions: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964

If that doesn't solve the problem, I'd run Apple Diagnostics and see whether it picks up on any hardware problems. If it does, the system should be taken to Apple or an Apple-authorized repair centre for further testing and repair.

Comment: thanks :) I will get a try. I meet this problem when move all data (include OS) from macbook late 2013 to macbook mid 2012. I don't know if I don't install os from fresh will meet this problem or not :)

Comment: can you tell me. Will Apple Diagnostic always check hardware problems ? If not, what should I do next. thanks :)

Comment: If the mid-2012 was used, it's possible that the PRAM has settings that are not compatible with your OS settings. You can reset the PRAM easily: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14222?viewlocale=en_US

Comment: I don't really see any changes. my computer maybe will be cooler if i increaser fan's speed. do you use this software ? Because I want to see normal setting of other mac. thanks :)

Comment: High CPU temperatures are not normal. You should have the system checked at a Genius Bar or authorized Apple repair centre.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone finding this thread (as I did) **long** after its initial post, I’d like to add something:

As a fellow MBP Retina mid-2020 i7 owner (2.8 GHz, though), I HIGHLY recommend a fan controller such as smcFanControl -- especially since in the case the OP’s fans are running at only HALF of their maximum speed despite the high temps.

I bought this mid-2012 because my last one died after temperature issues, and now when I see my temp creeping up to 50°C or more I crank the fans up to 5000+ RPM and see the temperature drop at least 10° even while rendering video.

Answer (score 1):

Had issues myself with a Mac of this vintage, with the chipset often running hot, which tended to cook the internals–several of which had to be replaced while still under AppleCare.

Besides the advice of resetting your SMC and PRAM, I'd also suggest an external cooling fan you could place upon the hotter areas of your machine, if you have an external keyboard/monitor setup where this could work. Doing this is also quieter than spinning up the internal fans, since they are larger and slower moving.